# TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Tags: python, pygame

When I attempt to run my program I end up with the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\terry\Thonny\Computer Science\Final Snake.py", line 134, in <module>
         pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("RED"),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1],10,10))
    TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
```

The error occurs on line 134 of my code. Here is the code that was used, detailed answers would be appreciated as I am rather new to pygame

```
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            #------------------------- quits the game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               game_over();
            #-------------------------

            #------------------------- movement of the snake
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.change_dir_to("RIGHT")
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    snake.change_dir_to("LEFT")
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.change_dir_to("UP")
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.change_dir_to("DOWN")
            #-------------------------

        #----------------------------- adds to score if the nake eats the food
        foodpos = food_spawner.spawn_food()
        if(snake.move(foodpos)==1):
            score+=1
            food_spawner.set_food_on_screen(False)
        #------------------------------

        #------------------------------ draws the screen, the snake, and its food
        window.fill(pygame.Color("BLACK"))
        for pos in snake.get_body():
            pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("BLUE"),pygame.Rect(pos[0],pos[1],10,10))
        pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("RED"),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1],10,10))
        #------------------------------
```

Comment: Under the `elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:`, you keep overwriting the same value. I'm not familiar with pygame, is that the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `foodpos` is not a list or tuple of integers.  It's possible to re-create this issue with the following code:

```
foodpos = [ 'apple', 'pie' ]         # NOTE: strings not integers
pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("RED"),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1],10,10))
```

Gives:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./rect_draw.py", Your exline 38, in 
>       pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("RED"),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect),10,10))
>   TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

The Pyagme rect object takes 4 *integers* in its constructor.  Please refer to [the manual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect).

Changing the content of `foodpos` to integers:

```
foodpos = [ 10, 10 ]         # NOTE: integers
pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("RED"),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1],10,10))
```

It works fine.

The example code does not show the content of `foodpos`, but whatever it has, making it integers will fix the issue.